# How to call an actor within itself in F# Akka

Tags: f#, actor, akka.net

The code I have is --

```
let mySlaveActor (mailbox: Actor<_>) =
    let rec loop() = actor {
        let mutable actor_id = -1
        let mutable rumor = ""
        let! rcv = mailbox.Receive()
        let sender = mailbox.Sender()
        match rcv with
        | MessageType2(idx) ->
             actor_id <- idx
        | MessageType8(neighbor) ->
             if (neighbor <> -1) then
                     let neighbor_slave = spawn mailbox (sprintf "workerActor%i" neighbor) mySlaveActor
                     neighbor_slave <! MessageType5(actor_id)
```

The current object is of a `mySlaveActor` whose name is `workerActor1` and I want to call `WorkerActor2` when the match is `MessageType8(..)`. But in the penultimate line, I get an error like --

```
The value or constructor `mySlaveActor` is not defined
```

Am I doing something wrong is my code missing something? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Have you tried to mark your function as recursive?